# Laravel 5 : Install custom component using Vue having error " is not in the npm registry."

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, npm

The technology we are using is Laravel and now were trying to use the Vue js. In my app.js

**App.js file**

```
Vue.component('main-chart-of-accounts', require('chart_of_account.vue').default);
```

Also in the same path. I have that file chart_of_account.vue. In this file this is our template

**chart_of_account.vue file**

```
<template>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
        <article-list></article-list>
        <!-- end card-->          
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import ChartOfAccountList from '../components/configurations/chart-of-accounts/ChartOfAccountList.vue';
    export default {  
        data: function () {
            return {
                detail: ''
            }
        },
        mounted(){
        },
        methods: {
        },
        watch: {
        },
        components: {
            ChartOfAccountList
        }
    }
</script>
```

Im encountering some errors when I tried to install my ChartOfAccount.vue by executing this command

*npm install --save ChartOfAccount.vue*

1) It said

'ChartOfAccount.vue@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 Your package name is not valid, because
npm ERR! 404  1. name can no longer contain capital letters

So I changed my file name to chart_of_account.vue then I tried to install it again but this time my error is

```
'chart_of_account.vue@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
```

Question: How do I import my chart_of_account.vue in my app.js?

Answer (score 0):

With `require()` you can import NPM packages by their name, like `require('express')`;

If you want to import a local file, you have to use a **relative path**, which for "current path" is `./`

So your code should be:

```js
Vue.component('main-chart-of-accounts', require('./chart_of_account.vue').default);
```

That way your bundler understands that you want a file, and not a package named "chart_of_account.vue"

Comment: Actually I already did that, but same error im encountered. 'chart_of_account.vue@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)